# C#: do not let the action run more than once at a time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a backend system that uses `.net 6` where I generate user names by manually auto increase.

Our user names are company and role based. So if we assume that we have the companies `a1` and `a2` and the roles `employee` and `manager`, we will have ids in the `{company}-{role}{number}` like `a1-e0001`, `a2-m0010`, ...

The code is something like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
public async Task<BaseDto?> Create([FromBody] reqDto)
{
    var lastUser = usersRepository
    .Where(e => e.Company == reqDto.Company && e.Role == reqDto.Role)
    .SortByUserName().LastOrDefault();

    var lastUserName = lastUser?.UserName;
    var lastUserNameInt = int.Parse(lastUserName.Split('-')[1]);
    var newUserName = e.Company + "-" + e.Role + (lastUserNameInt + 1);

    // create the user
    // ...
    // ...
```

The problem is when this method gets called more than once at a short duration, which is a realistic case, it will collide and give the same username to the 2 requests, as the second request will start running before the first one inserts the new user, so the second request also will get the same username.

What is a good way to avoid such collisions? I have thought of blocking the other calls to this question until the previous call resolves, but could not find a way how to do this.

Comment: If you really want to block the call you can use `SemaphoreSlim` https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/  or use `guid` as uniqe keys

Comment: Do you need the sequence to be in order? I usually use `Guid.NewGuid()` for scenarios like this.

Comment: @Philippe as the output I want is human readable usernames that I can provide to my users, `Guid` does not work for my case

Comment: @ConnorStoop thanks for the great resource, I will check it out and check if it works for me

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is to check to see if the user exists before creating, and then failing and asking for a re-try. Or if you're confident it doesn't happen often, you can just increase the number if it does exist. Best answer is from @vadim about using a db to control the id.

Comment: @Adnan the logic is fundamentally broken. `MAX+1` or `Last+1` will *always* generate duplicates if more than 2 connections execute the same code. They may do so if the latest rows are deleted even with a single client. *Don't* do that. Most databases have a SEQUENCE type or auto-incrementing columns. For those that don't you (MySQL, SQLite) you can create a table with sequences and last values.

Answer (score 2):

Blocking will work but will greatly decrease performance in your case. My solution would be to use some sort of db level manageable identity seed. For e.g. in MSSQL you can create table that will generate ID for you on insert like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC )
```

on insert you'll have thread safe ID and you can present it to your user later by simple concat `$"u-{ID}"`. This way you don't need to worry about concurrent access and you do have better login than with guid. I'm sure you don't need to stuck with MSSQL and your db engine can do this too.

Comment: The user name can be a computed column that concatenates the prefix with the ID

Comment: That is a good solution but something I have not added to my question which I thought was an unnecessary detail (realizing now that I should have provided it, I will now) is that I will actually be generating usernames institution and role based. so if we assume we have a1 and a2 institutions and employee and manager roles, there can be a variety of ids such as `a1-e0001`, `a2-e00005`, `a2-m0003`, so I need to be generating the numbers based on the latest username inserted for the specific institue and role, otherwise we will reach astronomical usernames such as like `u-43542` pretty quickly.

Comment: @Adnan "smart" keys are never a smart idea. What happens if a user changes role? Will you create a new user? Update all locations where the key is used? Or let the user keep the old and now misleading username? If you want to generate such *labels*, store the individual information and calculate the label at runtime. If all the info is in the same table you can use a computed column so applications and users never notice it's calculated

Comment: @adnan really it doesn't matter. You have unique id across all roles, you can present it anyway you like on UI without complicating things on db and backend level